# How to add extra fields in an Discord.js embed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having some trouble adding multiple fields in one embed. Adding one seems to be no problem. I have seen some other discord bots having multiple fields but I'm just not managing to get it right

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'my field title', value: 'some stuff' }
        { name: 'my field title2', value: 'some stuff' }
        { name: 'my field title3', value: 'some stuff' }
    )

    .setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(embed);
```

I just don't get it to work, if someone is able to help me out it would be great!
If you manage to get 2 fields on the same line it would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing `,` behind each field line.
Every `{ name: 'my field title', value: 'some stuff' }` should have `,` behind it expect the last field.

Example:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'my field title', value: 'some stuff' },
        { name: 'my field title2', value: 'some stuff' },
        { name: 'my field title3', value: 'some stuff' }
    )

    .setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(embed);
```

And if you want to have fields on the same line you should change the field to this

```js
{ name: 'my field title', value: 'some stuff', inline: true }
```

This was an easy thing to notice, yet next time try to show the exact error you receive to make it a bit easier to find the exact issue.

Comment: wow, that was a fast response. This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks man!

Comment: Thank you for not making fun of beginners on StackOverflow :) Some guy would've probably said "LOL you're so dumb, figure it out yourself".